# Logic to identify errors logged

Tags: batch-file, windows-10

How can I check for a particular text logged to a file in Win 10 ? There is a SAS daemon that fails occasionally and at which point logs a message to a log file (C:\SAS\logs\daemon_error.log). The message is logged (with timestamp) only when the error occurs. I want to write a program (and schedule to run every 15 mins)  which would check the occurrence of any error-message since the last error recognized. For e.g. if the last error was logged on July 15th the file would have looked like :

```
07-15-2018 13:21:42 : Incorrect parameters
```

Now if some error gets logged again today, it would look like below, at which point the script should trigger and identify it and send an email to a list of intended recipients. I presume there needs to be a mechanism to store the last timestamp when the error was recognized so that it only identify errors logged **after** the last one.

```
07-15-2018 13:21:42 : Incorrect parameters
09-10-2018 04:32:09 : Temp directory full
```

How can I accomplish this thru a batch file or perhaps any windows event(s). I do not have much knowledge on Win systems as I primarily worked on Unix. Can anyone please help ?
Thanks

Comment: To find stuff by date is one thing, if other events are written to the logs (info, warnings etc.) it will become a issue as you need to be specifc in your search to determine if these are actual errors. So do you have a list of events that are errors? are only errors logged to the file? etc..

Answer (score 0):

When I understood you correctly, you want to check for timestamp only to know, if there are new errors since the last check, but don't necessarily need to know, which errors. For that, I suggest using the "Archive attribute" (Windows sets this attribute at each write access to the file)

```
@echo off
:loop
timeout 900
dir /aa "C:\SAS\logs\daemon_error.log" >nul 2>&1 || goto :loop
echo The file was changed!
attrib -a "C:\SAS\logs\daemon_error.log"
goto :loop
```

The `dir` command will not find the file when the Archive attribute is not set (`/aa`) (or the file doesn't exist) and `|| goto :loop` will then jump to the `:loop` label.
`>nul 2>&1` will just discard any output of the `dir` command - we don't need it, just the errorlevel)
If the file was found (the Archive attribute is set, so we know, there was a write access), the code continues. Replace the `echo` command with the command to write an email (there are several questions/answers about that on SO).
`attrib -a` unsets the Archive attribute.

Note: Instead of the loop, I would set up a scheduled task, but keep with the loop for troubleshooting until you're sure, it works as intended.

Comment: the solution is perfect.. however, i m stuck on the sending mail part. I tried to invoke Powershell and run the script with contents - `$smtp.Send($smtpFrom,$smtpTo,$smtpSubj,$smtpBody)` OR `Send-MailMessage` but it fails with the error - `Send-MailMessage : Transaction failed. The server response was: Mail from xyz@abc.com rejected for policy reasons`. How can I resolve this ? or Can I send email from **CMD** directly without invoking **Powershell** ? thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, my Powershell knowledge is very basic (although the response suggests your command is basically correct). You should ask a new question for that.